# Scala Play Json implicit writes type mismatch

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to Scala and Play, and I ask for help with this simple example. I tried to search for solution by myself, but I did not succeed.
I am trying to do the example from from Mastering Play Framework for Scala book, the one about extending Json parser (Pages 29-30).

The environment I use is:

Scala: 2.11.7
Play: 2.5.8
Activator: 1.3.10

The code is:

```
case class Subscription(emailId: String, interval: Long)
```

In controller:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import play.api.libs.json.Writes

.....
val parseAsSubscription = parse.using { 
    request => 
      parse.json.map {
        body =>
          val  emailId:String = (body \ "emailId").as[String]
          val fromDate:Long = (body \ "fromDate").as[Long]
          Subscription(emailId, fromDate)
      }
  }

implicit val subWrites:Writes[Subscription] = Json.writes[Subscription]

def getSub = Action(parseAsSubscription) {
    request => 
      val subscription: Subscription = request.body
      Ok(Json.toJson(Subscription))
}
```

The line: `Ok(Json.toJson(Subscription))` gives an error

> No Json serializer found for type models.Subscription.type. Try to
>   implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

This is odd, because Writes object is defined one row above. Thus, I tried to pass it to toJson method explicitly:

`Ok(Json.toJson(Subscription)(subWrites))`

It gave me a different error, which partially explained why existing Writes object did not suit:

> type mismatch;
>   found:
>   play.api.libs.json.Writes[models.Subscription]
>   required:
>   play.api.libs.json.Writes[models.Subscription.type]

However, I don't understand the nature of this error and what `models.Subscription.type` is .
 I used to do a similar thing in a different example, and it worked just fine.
 Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to serialize the type `Subscription`, rather than the request body, which you stored as the value `subscription`. Try replacing the last line with `Ok(Json.toJson(subscription))`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Eric. That's really a sort of a dumb error from my side

Comment: You're welcome! The dumb errors are the most difficult ones to catch :)